# JavaScript regular expression for matching URL path components

Tags: javascript, regex, url, jslint

What JavaScript regular expression should I use to match individual components of a URL path? By path, I mean the path of the resource on the server, e.g. if the URL is 'http://example.com/directory/resource?start=0', the path is '/directory/resource'. By path components, I mean the /-separated parts of the path.

Let's say we have the URL 'http://example.com/component1/component2'. What I would like is to be able to match 'component1' or 'component2' with a grouped regular expression for each, so each component can be extracted, i.e. something like this: 'http://example.com/(*$component-regex*)/(*$component-regex*) (*$component-regex* being the regular expression we need to devise). In this example, there would be two matched groups: 'component1' and 'component2'.

Please come up with a regex that's considered safe by JSLint :) For example, it considers `[^/]+` insecure.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex for this:

```
var components = url.split(/[?#]/)[0].split("/").slice(3);
```

Okay, you do need a regex to split on one of two possible characters, but you could do it without any regex with this:

```
var components = url.split("#")[0].split("?")[0].split("/").slice(3);
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't lead directly to a solution, but maybe you've got a point wrt. splitting on '/' instead of using a regex. The root problem is mapping user-defined routes with variables to paths; e.g. user-defined route /:resource1/:resource2 (components starting with ':' are variables) to path /component1/component2, where you would get two variables component1 and component2. Do you suggest that I split the path on / in order to compare each component?